# how to get account details on clicking email address on particular person?

Tags: android, gmail, gmail-api

How to get account details on clicking email address of particular person in android as used in google application YouTubeGo

[image]

[Please take a look into image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNIqS.png)

Answer (score 0):

put below line in your manifeast file.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Then use below code to get configured email ids in the device which you had run.

*Code in Kotlin:*

```
  private fun getEmailID() {
    val listEmail: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()
    val emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS
    val accounts = AccountManager.get(this).accounts
    accounts.filter { emailPattern.matcher(it.name).matches() }
            .mapTo(listEmail) { it.name }
    val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listEmail)
    spinnerEmail.adapter = arrayAdapter
}
```

In Java use below:

```
  public String extractAddressFromAccountManager() {
    accountList = new ArrayList<>();

    Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8
    Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccountsByType("com.google");
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
            accountList.add(account.name);
            //return account.name;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Get Permission Like below:

```
    private boolean isGetAccountsPermissionAllowed() {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

if not granted use below to get:

```
   private void requestGetAccountsPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS}, GET_ACCOUNTS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Comment: I had got list of email id but i want accont details on clicking email id as used in youTubeGo.